# How to add existing item to Visual Studio project, copy to output but change it's original name?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, wix, csproj

I added a chm help file as link to the application's project but it's file name is not good for releasing to the public ("Compiled help.chm"). Unfortunately it's maintained in a different git submodule by other people and it's name is an automated output from their help builder.

After adding file as link there is no option to change the file name. Is there a csproj xml feature allowing user to rename a file link, possibly without breaking WiX installers depending on it and other undesired consequences?

Comment: if the help file path is hardcoded in WiX product file, I think you will break it by changing file name (unless you can modify wix installer project).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a bit curious about this one, so I gave it a try myself, and I think I was able to get something that will work for you:

1. If you have the file already in your project as a link, skip to 2; o/w, drag the file over your project in Visual Studio and - *while holding down both Ctrl and Shift* - drop the file on your project, creating a link.
2. Close the solution and project
3. Using notepad or some other text editor, edit the .csproj file, then locate your logical link by looking for the filename you just added.
4. Edit the link node as follows:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="....\OtherTeamOutputFolder\Compiled help.chm">
        <Link>Super Cool Production Product Name.chm</Link>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

5. Build your project; witness the glory.

Comment: I beg your pardon if this breaks with your WiX implementation, but with our projects, we were bypassing the .wixproj file altogether and writing all custom scripts, so this would have worked in that situation. However, I believe that one of two possibilities will exist 1. WiX will just handle it (i.e., get lucky, and it knows full syntax of project file links) 2. it will have some way to indicate aliases (seems we even used this in some of my projects)

Comment: It indeed works! It does not display the updated name in the solution explorer though but hack is a hack... I changed WiX to grab *.chm so no issues with it. Thanks.

Comment: @faisalhafeez so what?

Comment: @JohnCastleman I am trying it for cs file. Do you know any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you control WiX project, you can specify file name in the `file` element:

```
<Component…>
  <File Id=”FILE_MyProgramDir_SomeAssemblyDLL”
    Name=”SomeNewNameForAssembly.dll”
    Source=”SomeAssembly.dll”
    KeyPath=”yes” />
</Component>
```

However, you should consider the new name while accessing to renamed resources both from your executable/class libraries and from other stuff.