# Change name of file added as link in vsproj

Tags: c#

I have a file lets say Release2014.cs. This file is shared between different projects so I need to add this file as a link in my c# project. Adding this file as link works completely fine. But what I want is to rename this file to something else lets say `Release.cs` without changing the original file name. Is it possible?

In csproj, I see this

```
<Compile Include="..\Release2014.cs">   // Path to original file
  <Link>Release2014.cs</Link>
</Compile>
```

I replaced `<Link>Release2014.cs</Link>` as `<Link>Release.cs</Link>`. But this doesn't work.

What I am getting,

[image]

What I want,

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188872/how-to-add-existing-item-to-visual-studio-project-copy-to-output-but-change-it

Comment: This works because chm file is not used in compilation. It is renamed and copied to output directory. My problem is with compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create symbolic file (and directory) links in Windows, use the mklink command from an elevated command prompt. Run mklink to see the options and parameters. This way you could create a project specific filename and add that to your project.